# DataContract runtime error - Type 'myType' cannot be serialized. What i'm doing wrong?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, exception, datacontract

Trying to pass "complex" class type that contains primitive types with interfaces and lists of interfaces/classes.

I guess the problematic member is:

```
public List<IMyInterface> IntrfList
```

Runtime Error:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http:/localhost/xxxxxx/xxxxxService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

The descriptive error from MS Service Trace Viewer (SvcTraceViewer):

> Type 'myType' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

I did as the explanation suggests but didn't help.

The "shared" class:

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
    public class ServerState
    {
        private Queue<IJob> _mWaitingQueue;
        public Queue<IJob> mWaitingQueue
        {
            get
            {
                lock (_LockObjWaiting)
                {
                    return _mWaitingQueue;
                }
            }
            private set
            {
                _mWaitingQueue = value;
            }
        }
        private object _LockObjWaiting = new object();

        private List<IJob> _mInPrograssList = new List<IJob>();

        [DataMember]
        public List<IJob> mInPrograssList
        {
            get
            {
                    return _mInPrograssList;
            }
            private set
            {
                _mInPrograssList = value;
            }
        }
}
```

IJob is an interface.
The structure of IJob is like this:

```
IJob (Interface)
  - JobBase (Abstract class)
    - JobA (Driven from JobBase)
    - JobB (Driven from JobBase)
```

Comment: Could you paste your class myType? There is probably something wrong with it's data annotations.

Comment: So is "myType" == `ServerState`? The `IJob` implementations need to be serialized too. Are they serializable?

Comment: Also, at least in this sample, your use of locks is questionable.

Comment: Yes, "myType" is ServerState.
And yes again, locks should not be used within DataMember type properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, got it!

I posted the solution in my blog: http://livshitz.wordpress.com/2012/11/06/wcf-serialization-datacontract-runtime-error-type-mytype-cannot-be-serialized/

After fighting and cutting all possible parts of that “shared” class, I got to the problematic area.

The problem was that I used interface as a member (or list of..), which associated with Driven classes.

And that’s it! The serializer having problem figuring out how to serialize that member, so here is the solution:

When using interface as a member (or list of interface) in a class that is about to be serialized and shared via WCF, the *Shared* class must specify the *possible* types of the interface by adding to it:

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownType(typeof(JobA))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownType(typeof(JobB))]
```

And each of those types must be marked with:

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
```

Note: Since JobBase is abstract, no reason to mark it with KnownType...

That’s it.